# Spring Data neo4j - Id generation strategies

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm working on an example project in which I have a model class `Movie` and I want this movie to have a `UUID` as the identifier. 
I tried the following code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.List; 

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {

@Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy="uuid2")
private String id;


private String title;

private int released;

private String tagline;

@Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

public Movie() {
}

public Movie(String title, int released, String tagline) {

    this.title = title;
    this.released = released;
    this.tagline = tagline;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getReleased() {
    return released;
}

public String getTagline() {
    return tagline;
}

public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}


public void addRole(Role role) {
    this.roles.add(role);
}
}
```

This code is generating an error.

`org.neo4j.ogm.exception.MappingException: No identity field found for class: movies.spring.data.neo4j.domain.Movie`

[here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference:annotating-entities:graph-id) is the reference I used to write this code 
I am using `neo4j-ogm-core:2.1.3`
I didn't understand what was in the reference fully. 
but I needed to import `Hibernate` to use `@GenericGenerator`

**Question:**

How can I use UUID inside my model. knowing that I'm using `Spring Data`?

*Note*: I am new to `Neo4j` and `Spring`. I am having difficulties asking the proper questions.

Comment: what is this GenericGenerator ?

Comment: @pvpkiran
GenericGenerator as described in the this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/GenericGenerator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the [GraphAware Neo4j UUID](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid). According the library REDME file:

> GraphAware UUID is a simple library that transparently assigns a UUID
>   to newly created nodes and relationships in the graph and makes sure
>   nobody can (accidentally or intentionally) change or delete them.

Simply download [GraphAware Neo4j Framework](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) and GraphAware Neo4j UUID .jar files to `/plugins` directory, modify [few lines](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-uuid#setup-and-configuration) in `neo4j.conf` file and restart Neo4j. After it, `UUIDs` will be assigned to each node / relationships created in the Neo4j graph.

This approach does not depends on Spring.

Comment: I added th jar files and added the lines to my `neo4j.confg` file 
restarted the server. 
created a new node 
the node <id> is an integer 
I also added lines to determine UUID generator 

`com.graphaware.module.UUID.1=com.graphaware.module.uuid.UuidBootstrapper`

`com.graphaware.module.UUID.relationship=com.graphaware.runtime.policy.all.IncludeAllBusinessRelationships`

`com.graphaware.module.UUID.uuidGeneratorClass=com.graphaware.module.uuid.generator.JavaUtilUUIDGenerator`

but can't seem to understand the full recipe 
can you please provide any further help ?

Comment: Hi @Ali.Wassouf. The `id` is a internal identifier for nodes and relationships used by the Neo4j engine. The UUID property added by GraphAware Neo4j UUID is stored in a property called `uuid` in each node or relationship. Your nodes does not contains this property?

Comment: Also, you can customize the property name changing the config line `com.graphaware.module.UIDM.uuidProperty`.

Comment: Unfortunately, my nodes do not contain this property.